# How to transfer campaign_id, medium_id and source_id from crm.lead to sale.order in odoo v9?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

Does anyone know how to or has anyone already realized that the values of `campaign_id`, `medium_id` and `source_id` (that can be entered in an opportunity) get transferred to the quotation when the user clicks on "Convert to quotation"?

Currently, odoo seems to ignore these and just link the opportunity. However, this makes it hard to track campaign success.

I know that I'll probably have to create a custom module for this and I've tried but couldn't really figure out where these values should be passed.

Hope someone can help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes Odoo does **not** pass these fields to the sale order. But why do you need them there? If you want to track a campaign's success you can do it by setting filters on `crm.lead` records.

If this does not work for you then yes, you have to create a custom module to implement this functionality.

[image: Check filters on the top right]

Comment: Hi George, thanks for your answer! There are different reasons why I'd need the campaign info in my sale order: * to know what amount was actually quoted; * if a sales employee decides to create a quotation right away I'd also like to collect campaign info. I've found this OCA module which does this vor v9 https://github.com/OCA/crm/tree/10.0/crm_sale_marketing. It passes the values by using default parameters in the view `'default_campaign_id': campaign_id,'default_medium_id': medium_id,'default_source_id': source_id` However, this **does not work in v10** and I can't understand why...